# Can't pull the images from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have uploaded some image files. But I can't show them on the page. Here is how it looks like now:
This is uploading

```
foreach($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
{
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['photo']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['photo']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['photo']['type'][$key];  
    $photo= "0". $_FILES['photo']['name'][0];
    $photo2=$file_name = $key.$_FILES['photo']['name'][1];
    $photo3= $file_name = $key.$_FILES['photo']['name'][2];
}

mysql_query("insert into $table(ID,Name,Photo1,Photo2,Photo3,Text) 
            values('$id','$fullname','$photo','$photo2','$photo3','$text')");
```

And this is how I am trying to show the images:

```
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT *FROM Creative");
        while ($f = mysql_fetch_array($query)):
    ?>
    <tr bgcolor="#c0c0c0">
        <td><?php echo '<img src="creative/"'.$f['Photo1'].'width="50" height="50" alt=""></img>'; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo '<img src="creative/"'.$f['Photo2'].'width="50" height="50" alt=""></img>'; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo '<img src="creative/"'.$f['Photo3'].'width="50" height="50" alt=""></img>'; ?></td>

    </tr>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, but what happens? Does the upload works? Is the data inserted on the DB? What debugging you've done?

Comment: @jd182 - as you can see, OP is storing filenames in the database.

Answer (score 0):

the expression

```
$photo2=$file_name = $key.$_FILES['photo']['name'][1];
```

is wrong. Your `foreach` iterates over every `$_FILES['photo']` uploaded. Thus `$_FILES['photo']['name']`is the name of just one of the files. `$_FILES['photo']['name'][1]`is the second character of your filename.

If you want to store three photos in just one row, you first have to loop (three times), collect that and than issue the SQL rather then indexing the filename liken an array.

Look at [file upload](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)